# How to download documents from liferay from outside application ..using liferay jsonws or any other way

Tags: liferay

Hi i am using liferay/api/secure/jsonws services to upload documents, getting documents, from a outside application , in the same way i want to download the documents also, i checked my liferay jsonws , there is no method or service which i can use for download , or i don't know about it , please suggest me a way to download documents from outside application , by using jsonws or any other way is also fine.

Edit after i got to know how to download document.

Hi I tried to download liferay document from outside application by using getURl, but every time for all document i am getting liferay login page content

i have already tried get-file-as-stream json-rpc call but that also giving me null response

the code which i have used is:

```
 final HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(hostname.trim());
    System.out.println(targetHost.getHostName());
    UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
    System.out.println(creds);
    final AuthScope authscope = new AuthScope(targetHost);
    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(authscope, creds);

    final AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
    final BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
    authCache.put(targetHost, basicAuth);

    final BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);

    final HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(hostname+"/documents/" + groupId + "/" + folderId + "/" + filename);


    final HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httpget, localContext);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        final org.apache.http.HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            entity.writeTo(baos);
            return baos.toByteArray();
        }
    }
    return null;
} finally {
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

}

i am adding basic auth header will correct username and password, don't know how this login page is coming, is there any permission which i need to change or any configurations issue, please help in this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Liferay WebDav Services to download files from your document-library. The paths to download can be inspected inside of the control-panel when clicking on a file entry (WebDAV URL toogle link). The paths usually look like: /webdav/{site-name}/document_library/{folder-name}/{file-name}
Otherwise, you could mimic the request URLs Liferay creates inside the documents-media portlet to download the file entry.
But you should take care about authentication, when your files (and folders) are not visible to guests.

Comment: i have tried that, i used basic auth with same username and password which i am using to login to my application,authentication got failed, can you please tell me more about how to do authentication, if you can provide me sample code so that will be helpful.